# How to show PDF preview in IE11 with Blob URI

Tags: vue.js, pdf, internet-explorer

I'm building a web page that shows PDF preview with Vue.

However, the page doesn't show PDF preview in only IE11. It seems to me that the reason why it doesn't show PDF preview in IE11 is `:src` attribute in `iframe` has **Blob URI** .

*I konw it works if `:src` attribute has `HTTP/HTTPS URI`.*

This is my source code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      PDF Preview
    </div>
    <iframe
      width="560"
      height="315"
      :src="pdfBlobURL"
    >

    </iframe>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        pdfBlobURL: ''
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$axios.post("/api/url/to/fetch/pdfBlobData", { id: 1 }, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .then(function(response) {
          // create Blob URI by pdfBlob data that is fetched from backend
          this.pdfBlobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.pdfBlob)
        }.bind(this))
    }
  }
</script>
```

Do you guys know how to show PDF Preview in IE11 with **Blob URI**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Internet Explorer does not support the use of DATA URIs as the source of IFRAMEs.

As an alternative workaround, in the IE browser, I suggest you could download the PDF file first, then, using IE browser to display the PDF file.

You could refer to the following code:

```
function myfunction() {
    var data = "BASE64STRING";
    var fileName = "test.pdf";
    //For IE using atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var byteCharacters = window.atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
        // Directly use base 64 encoded data for rest browsers (not IE)
        var base64EncodedPDF = data;
        var pdfWindow = window.open();
        pdfWindow.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64EncodedPDF+'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');

    }
}
```

Besides, you could try to use the ES5 version of [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and pdf.worker.js version (Here is a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/6fv1ocej/1/) about using pdf.js, it works well on my side using IE11, you can check it):

- pdf.js ES5 version: `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.js`
- pdf.worker.js ES5 version: `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.worker.js`